# how to increment a gridview cell value on same record

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview, increment

i have 7 columns (code, sales man, description, size, QTY, price, amount).
how can i increment in QTY column if the record is same. this should be 2 if the quantity is 1 before.

[image]

here is the code

```
private void MakeDataTable()
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Code");
        dt.Columns.Add("Sales Man");
        dt.Columns.Add("Description");
        dt.Columns.Add("Size");
        dt.Columns.Add("QTY");
        dt.Columns.Add("Price");
        dt.Columns.Add("Amount");
    }
private void AddToDataTable()
    {

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                if (quantity != 0)
                {   dr["Code"] = sdr["bnSKU"].ToString();
                    dr["Sales Man"] = txtsmCode.Text;
                    dr["Description"] = cat_brnd.ToString();
                    dr["Size"] = sdr["nSizeCode"].ToString();

                    dr["QTY"] = txtqnt.Text;

                    dr["Price"] = sdr["strSalePrice"].ToString();
                    dr["Amount"] = amount.ToString();
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }


            }
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            sdr.Close();


            con.Close();
        }
    }
    private void BindGrid()
    {
        gvsale.DataSource = dt;
        gvsale.DataBind();

    }
protected void gvsale_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
        e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;}
```

Comment: what is your main identtiy cloumn...

Comment: when you say : "how can i increment in QTY column if **the record is same.**", based on what column are you making your comparison ?

Comment: "code" column i want to make comparison and if the record is exist in datagridview row then it should be increment in quantity instead of creating another row.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand what you mean, but since you want to increment a cell based on an identifier column, i think you should follow those steps in general :

**1- Get the list of all code in the DataGridView :** this method give you a list containing all codes in the your DataGridView

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Return a list of string containing all the codes
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>List of codes</returns>
        private List<string> GetListOfCodes()
        {
            return
                (from DataGridViewRow row in gvsale.Rows
                      select (string)row.Cells[0].Value).ToList();
        }
```

**2- Check if the code you want add already exists :** This method checks if the code you want to add already exists, if yes it return its index, if no : it return -1.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return the index row of a code if it exits, if not return -1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="code">the code you are looking for</param>
    /// <returns>its index</returns>
    private int ReturnIndexOfCodeIfAlreadyExists(string code)
    {
        var list = GetListOfCodes();
        if (list.Contains(code))
        {
            return list.IndexOf(code);
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

**3- Make method that increment QTY in row using the row Index :** here the method that increment the QTY value in row index passed in parameters :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Increment the QTA in that the row using the index
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">index of the row you want to increment</param>
    private void IncrementQTAofIndex(int index)
    {
        int qty = Convert.ToInt32(gvsale.Rows[index].Cells["QTY"].Value);
        qty++;
        gvsale.Rows[index].Cells["QTY"].Value = qty;
    }
```

**4- Finally you just check before adding :** if the code's you want to add, exists or not:

```
        var newCode = sdr["bnSKU"].ToString();
        var indexIfExists = ReturnIndexOfCodeIfAlreadyExists(newCode);
        if (indexIfExists == -1)
        {
            //...Means the code doesn't exists in the DataGridView...
            //...So you add a new Row!
        }
        else
        {
            //...Means the code exist already and you need to just 
            //...Increment QTY
            IncrementQTAOfIndex(indexIfExists);
        }
```

i hope this is what you are looking, anyway this is how i would solve that problem.

1- Get existing Items

2- Check if the item i want to add exists

3- if yes : get its index and increment

4- if no : just add it in new row

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. i did it what i want but with different logic.

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
DataRow[] r;
 r = dt.Select("Code = " + sdr["bnSKU"].ToString());
                    if (r.Length > 0)
                    {
                        r[0]["QTY"] = Convert.ToInt32(r[0]["QTY"]) +Convert.ToInt32( txtqnt.Text);
                        r[0]["Amount"] = Convert.ToInt32( r[0]["QTY"]) * rate;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr["Code"] = sdr["bnSKU"].ToString();
                        //dr["Sales Man"] = txtsmCode.Text;
                        dr["Description"] = cat_brnd.ToString();
                        dr["Size"] = sdr["nSizeCode"].ToString();

                        dr["QTY"] = txtqnt.Text;

                        dr["Price"] = sdr["strSalePrice"].ToString();
                        dr["Amount"] = amount.ToString();
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
```